# Extract all JSON keys

Tags: sql, json, presto

I have a JSON column `j` like:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': {'b1': 3, 'b2': 5}}
{'c': 3, 'a': 5}
{'d': 1, 'c': 7}
```

How can I get all distinct (top-level) key names from Presto? I.e. I something like

```
select distinct foo(j)
```

To return

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

(note that in this instance I'm not too concerned with the nested keys)

[Presto documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) doesn't have any function that explicitly fits the bill. The only thing that looks close is mention of [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) syntax, but even this seems to be inaccurate. At least one of the following should return *something* but all failed in Presto for me:

```
select json_extract(j, '$.*')
select json_extract(j, '$..*')
select json_extract(j, '$[*]')
select json_extract(j, '*')
select json_extract(j, '..*')
select json_extract(j, '$*.*')
```

Further, I suspect this will return the *values*, not the keys, from `j` (i.e., `[2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 1, 7]`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can

1. extract JSON top-level keys with `map_keys(cast(json_column as map<varchar,json>))`
2. later "flatten" the key collections using [`CROSS JOIN UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest)
3. then you can `SELECT DISTINCT` to get distinct top-level keys.

Example putting this together:

```
presto> SELECT DISTINCT m.key
     -> FROM (VALUES JSON '{"a": 2, "b": {"b1": 3, "b2": 5}}', JSON '{"c": 3, "a": 5}')
     ->     example_table(json_column)
     -> CROSS JOIN UNNEST (map_keys(CAST(json_column AS map<varchar,json>))) AS m(key);
 key
-----
 a
 b
 c
(3 rows)
```

Comment: An added proviso that if your column is stored as `varchar` like `'{"a": 2, "b": {"b1": 3, "b2": 5}}'`, you'll want to convert to `JSON` with `json_parse(json_column)`, _not_ `cast(json_column as JSON)`

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a `CROSS JOIN`? On a DB with > 1 billion rows, this is very slow.

Comment: My approach now is: zoom in to a small enough subset of the data where I can execute (something like 7 million rows, where I found 36 unique keys); then add a `where not key in (keys_found_from_narrow_query)` clause to a wider query. 1) is this actually a better approach to finding unique keys in the whole data set 2) is there a better/less iterative way to implement this at scale?