# Identifying unique keys in presto

Tags: sql, database, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to identify unique keys in json schema as shown below using presto. While there are multiple examples in SO - I am unable to use any solution for below example

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT '{"name": "Susan Smith",
           "org": "engineering",
           "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},
           {"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}'
    AS users
)
```

Expected output with keys

```
Column
name
org
projects
```

Reference SO links referred
SO link1 : [Extract all JSON keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588077/extract-all-json-keys)

SO Link 2 : [Presto identify unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926351/presto-identify-unique-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions should work just fine for you, you just need to convert your `varchar` column into json with `json_parse` (I use succinct syntax for `cross join unnest`):

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT '{"name": "Susan Smith",
           "org": "engineering",
           "projects": [{"name":"project1", "completed":false},
           {"name":"project2", "completed":true}]}'
    AS users
)

-- query
select key
from dataset,
unnest(map_keys(cast(json_parse(users) as map(varchar, json)))) as t(key);
```

Output:

| key |
| --- |
| name |
| org |
| projects |